# GridView's NewValues and OldValues empty in the OnRowUpdating event

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-3.5

I have the GridView below.  I am binding to a custom datasource in the code behind.  It gets into the "OnRowUpdating" event just fine, but there are no NewValues or OldValues.  Any suggestions as to how I can get these values?

```
<asp:GridView   ID="gv_Personnel" 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnRowDataBound="gv_Personnel_DataBind" 
                        OnRowCancelingEdit="gv_Personnel_CancelEdit" 
                        OnRowEditing="gv_Personnel_EditRow" 
                        OnRowUpdating="gv_Personnel_UpdateRow"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                        ShowFooter="true" 
                        DataKeyNames="BudgetLineID"
                        AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
                        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"
                        >
            <Columns>                 
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Level of Staff" DataField="LineDescription" />
                <%--<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Hrs/Units requested" DataField="NumberOfUnits" />--%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hrs/Units requested">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("NumberOfUnits")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tb_NumUnits" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NumberOfUnits")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Hrs/Units of Applicant Cost Share" DataField="" NullDisplayText="0" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Hrs/Units of Partner Cost Share" DataField="" NullDisplayText="0" />
                <asp:BoundField FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true" FooterText="TOTAL PERSONNEL SERVICES:" HeaderText="Rate" DataFormatString="{0:C}" DataField="UnitPrice" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount Requested" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"  FooterStyle-BorderWidth="2" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true"/>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Applicant Cost Share" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-BorderWidth="2" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true"/>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Partner Cost Share" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-BorderWidth="2" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true"/>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Projet Cost" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-BorderWidth="2" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true"/>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Regarding on the GridView control's
>   RowUpdating event problem, it is the
>   expected behavior because when we do
>   not associate GridView(or other
>   ASP.NET 2.0 databound control) with
>   DataSource control, it won't
>   automatically query and fill the
>   parameters collection of the
>   updating/deleting/... events.  In such
>   cases, we need to manually extract the
>   field values from the Template
>   control.

This is what says a Microsoft employee in [here](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/asp-net-datagrid/3487/GridView-DataSource-RowUpdating-e-OldValues-and-e-NewValues).

In that case you can do it using the [ExtractValuesFromCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.extractvaluesfromcell.aspx) method to make the NewValues collection yourself.

EDIT:

I found a piece of code in the comments of [this](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2006/08/24/DataBinding-in-ASP.NET-2.0-and-the-RowUpdating-event.aspx) blog:

```
protected void OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{     
       GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
       gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
       gv.DataBind();
       ...
}

protected void OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
   for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
   {
      DataControlFieldCell cell = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i] as DataControlFieldCell;
      gv.Columns[i].ExtractValuesFromCell(e.NewValues, cell, DataControlRowState.Edit, true);
   }
   // now you can use NewValues collection normally
}
```

Havent tested it, but seems to solve the problem, let me know if it did.

Comment: try e.Keys instead gv.Columns[i].ExtractValuesFromCell(e.NewValues, cell,

Comment: In my case, the manuel cell values extraction didn't change anything : the NewValues collection remains empty.

Answer (score 6):

Im not sure if this would help..but this is what i found in msdn [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx)

> The Keys, OldValues and NewValues collections are automatically populated only when the GridView control is bound to data by using the DataSourceID property.

Comment: So are you saying that those values can only be used if you are defining and using a datasource on the aspx page?

Comment: I'm not sure for I haven't tried but the statement says you need to use the DataSourceID property in binding with the GridView. I might try that and see if you can assign an ID to a datasource and bind it in code behind. If not I'll try the suggestion below =)

Answer (score 2):

I was doing databinding in my Page_Load event and when I clicked "Update" the PostBack was done, so was the Page_Load event fired. GridView was filled with the old values again, so in myGrid.RowUpdating event I couldn't retrieve new values. If this helps

Answer (score 1):

Bind in the Page PreRender event handler like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    GridBinder()
End Sub
```

NB: PreRender takes place after the RowUpdating event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the IsPostback in the form load. When the gridview's Update did the postback, it first refreshed with the old values. Use IsPostback to prevent this:

```
If Not IsPostback Then 

   ' Data bind here

End If
```

This way, it will not overwrite the "new" gridview values

Comment: This does not explain why *old values* are null and hence is not the solution to the issue. It's a common mistake, however, to rebind the grid willy nilly.